# How to use Cascade inside kendo grid dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Actually my requirement is to get the Activity Name when ever the WorkcenterName getting change i need to display corresponding activity in dropdown. Activity i will get from gridData(this is variable in my example).

I tried using cascadeFrom , I am not able to get the value. I hope i explained my requirement clearly.

Here with attached Dojo link. Please have a look my code and give the solutions for this.
http://dojo.telerik.com/APeVA

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a couple of thing wrong with your dojo code and update your dojo [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/@pdcoogan/ENIfO) with a working sample. Here is a list of some of the problems I found, the solution was probably a combination more than 1 of these.

1. There was no `cascadeFrom` or `cascadeFromField` defined in your activity drop down.
2. I normalized your `gridData` data set, separating the activities into a separate list that I used to fill the activities drop down. I replaced it with an `ActivityId` in the `gridData`. Kendo data sources do not support a object or array field types.
3. Added a `name` attribute to the workCenterName drop down so it could be found by cascade setting.
4. Added an id to the gridData, this helped the edit/cancel/delete work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I have done that in a .cshtml. Hope this can help you.

I have defined the columns as follows:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Servicio, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["SER"], "CodServicio", "DesCorta").Width(75).EditorTemplateName("ServicioTemplate").Title(Recursos.Resource.SERVICIO);
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Seccion, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["SEC"], "CodSeccion", "DesCorta").Width(75).EditorTemplateName("SeccionTemplate").Title(Recursos.Resource.SECCION);
```

The secret here is `.EditorTemplateName()`. I have a folder, in a specific location. Not sure if you can change that, but I think it must be in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates and there I have defined both dropdowns, the second one with `.CascadeFrom()` property just as you would use it outside of a grid.
Hope this can help you, feel free to ask anything you need!